# dynamically generating plugin syntax

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded an audio player plugin for WP. the syntax is very simple. You just add the line : "**[audio:my_file.mp3]**" to your post editor/excerpt, and call it in the loop with **the_content()** or **the_excerpt()** respectively. 
I would like to build a metabox in which the user would upload a file, and the plugin syntax would automatically be generated accordingly. I know how to insert the meta-data into the DB, but pulling it with **get_post_meta()** or **the_meta()** just gets the syntax as it is, without replacing it with the desired plugin content (i.e the audio player).
I thought about dynamically injecting the syntax to the editor\excerpt with the use of the filter **default_content** but this filter only applies to normal posts, whereas mine is a custom post type (audio).
your ideas are most welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. used **the_content** filter, which allows you to inject content directly from the code:

```
    function inject_audio_plugin_syntax($content) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == 'audios') {
    $mf_plugin = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "mf_plugin", true );
    return $mf_plugin;
    }
    return $content;
    }

    add_filter('the_content', 'inject_audio_plugin_syntax', 0);
```